# Impact of US Monetary Policy on the Indian Economy

Tags: finance

Why does an increase in the repo rate in the United States have an impact on the economy of India, even when India has raised its own repo rate?

In other words, why is the monetary policy decision of the Federal Reserve in the USA relevant to the economy of India, even though India has taken steps to control its own monetary policy through adjustments to its repo rate?